# MenuItem ActionView height always matches the ActionBar height

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have one `MenuItem` with an `ActionView` set.
This `ActionView` is just a `FrameLayout` with a `TextView` in it.
Both the `FrameLayout` and the `TextView` have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` set.
The `TextView` also has a yellow background to make it look like a button.
However the background always fills the whole height of the `ActionBar`. How can I make this button to actually look like a button?

If I set margins to the `TextView` then it works but I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: What if you used a Button instead of a TextView?

Comment: A need a textView. I have seen some examples in which the height is fixed to 32dp... this also works but I don't get why wrap_content doesn't work.

Comment: If it works, then maybe you should do that. It's possible the AcitonBar is doing some default handling for the layout params for the views it shows; maybe looking at it in Hierarchy Viewer will help you.